# How to remove 'Web Load Balancer' from an application on Openshift

Tags: openshift

I have an openshift free plan account, and I am running 2 applications. The first one with 2 gears (for PHP and Web Load Balancer) and another application with 1 gear (for PHP).

Now, i out of free gears. My question is:

How to remove 'Web Load Balancer' from my first application ?

(I need remove 'Web Load Balancer' to save a gear for another catridge which i will install later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web load balancer should not consume another gear. It should rather scale your app according to the limits that are set. Perhaps you want to [limit the number of gears it scales the app over](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-scaling.html#managing-application-scaling) to one gear max only?

Or maybe you have a database cartridge attached to your app, which would be accommodated on a separate gear indeed, in case of a scalable application.

In any case, if you want to remove the web load balancer from your app, I'm afraid you will need to delete the app and recreate it as non-scalable. Before deleting the app, you probably want to [back it up](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-backing-up-applications.html) first.

Comment: Thank @Jiri Fiala, I've just deleted my app after created snapshot for it. Maybe only this way to remove Web load balancer in Openshift.